# In Graph Facebook API, how can I get the user's id given users's email?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

We are creating an integration with Facebook Workplace.

The only information we have about users is their email address. We require to find the user's Id in order to use the API and receiving webhook events.

How can we do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly with the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/graph-api/member), you just need to call the graph apis endpoint adding the user email address at the end of the url

GET /{email_address} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

The Workplace integration needs **Read user email addresses** permissions, otherwise you will not be able to perform the call.